# Disable select option that is created dynamically from db

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a select dropdown that is created using a `@foreach` in Laravel Blade.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg d-block" id="recipeIngredientSelect">
    <option selected disabled>Select a recipe ingredient...</option>
    @foreach($recipe->ingredients as $ingredient)
      <option value="{{$ingredient->id}}">{{$ingredient->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addIngredient"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am submitting the form via Ajax with jQuery using the `onClick` of the `addIngredient` button.

I'm also trying to add the `disabled` attribute to the option that the user selects when clicking on the save button, so that they cannot choose the item again.

I'm unsure how I go about this, with the content being created dynamically.

The actual select output for reference:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <select id="recipeIngredientSelect" class="custom-select custom-select-lg d-block">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a recipe ingredient...</option>
        <option value="2">Chicken Thighs</option>
        <option value="3">English Mustard</option>
        <option value="4">Creme Freiche</option>
        <option value="5">Puff Pastry</option>
        <option value="6">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="7">Vegetable Stock</option>
        <option value="8">Spring Onions</option>
    </select>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" id="addIngredient" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

The following is the page. The user clicks on the select dropdown, and chooses an item. When they click the plus button, it's added to the table below via jQuery append.

[image]

At this point, I want to disable the option within the select, so that the user can't select the item twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#addIngredient').on('click', function () {
    $('#recipeIngredientSelect option:selected').attr('disabled', '');
});
```

`option:selected` CSS pseudo selector is used to select the `option` element that is selected from the dropdown.

This disables the selected option once the button is clicked. So, it can't be selected again.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this where `$selected->id` is the id the user selects

```
@foreach($recipe->ingredients as $ingredient)
    <option value="{{$ingredient->id}}" @if($ingredient->id == $selected->id) disabled @endif>{{$ingredient->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, as the page isn't being reloaded on button click. The info is just being saved to an array, which is then sent to the controller once the user clicks the finished button.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you just want to remove the `option` from the select after the element is added to the table (then if `option` is removed from the table add it back to the select). I can't give anymore because I don't know the code you are using to add the `option` to the table.